# Looping through a variable array and inserting using bind_param

Tags: php, mysqli, bindparam

Im trying to loop through several arrays to insert data into a mysql database. And Im trying to bind the data so that I can loop through it. There can be a various number of columns to which data is bound.

It appears that the data Im binding is not being processed as expected and the insert ultimately fails.

I have a columns array that stores the column names and data types. I also have a values array that stores the values that are to be inserted. Sample data:

```
$colArr = array (
    array('i', 'ID'),
    array('s', 'Date')
);

$valArr = array(
    array(1, 'now()'),
    array(2, 'now()'),
);

//I create my type and query strings as well as the array referencing the columns for binding.

$valStrForQry = rtrim(str_repeat('?, ', count($v['colArr'])), ', '); //result: '?, ?'
$params = array();
$colsForQry = '';
$typeStr = '';
$cntr = 0;
foreach ($colArr as $cols) {
    $colsForQry .= $cols[1] . ', ';
    $typeStr .= $cols[0];
    $params[] = &$valArr[$cntr][1];
    $cntr++;
}

$colsForQry = rtrim($colsForQry, ', '); //result: 'ID, Date'

$qry = 'INSERT INTO table (' . $colsForQry . ') VALUES (' . $valStrForQry . ')';
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($qry);

//Bind the parameters.

call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_param'), array_merge(array($typeStr), $params));

//Loop through the values array, assign them using eval, and execute the statement. Im open to suggestions if theres a better way to do this.

foreach ($valArr as $vals) {
    $cntr = 0;
    foreach ($colArr as $c) {
        eval('$' . $c[1] . ' = ' . $vals[$cntr] . ';');
        $cntr++;
    }

    if ($stmt->execute() === FALSE) {
        //show $stmt->error for this iteration
    } else {
        //show success for this iteration
    }
}
```

The first iteration results in a successful insertion of incorrect data. That is, the inserted ID is 0, not 1, and no other info is inserted. The second iteration (and all consecutive ones) results in the following error message: Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'

What am I doing wrong here, is it the eval or something else? Im not sure how to figure this one out.

Comment: Just adding, in case it isnt obvious, the database table is set up with ID as the primary key.

Comment: Can't tell at a glance, but put the string you're constructing in a var and dump it before the eval, maybe there's something wrong there that isn't immediately obvious.

Comment: The strings for the eval statement look correct: $ID = 1; and $Date = now();

Comment: I meant the full string.. e.g. replace `eval('$' . $c[1] . ' = ' . $vals[$cntr] . ';');` with `$foo = '$' . $c[1] . ' = ' . $vals[$cntr] . ';'; print("$foo\n"); eval($foo);` just to make sure you're eval'ing what you think you are.

Comment: Yes, thats how I confirmed that the strings being evaled look correct.

Comment: It may just be that you can't combine binding and eval in that way.  FWIW there's no real reason to.  You can get rid of the early binding with `call_user_func_array` and just issue `$stmt->bind_param(...)` inside your loop instead.

Comment: Commenting out call_user_func_array and adding $stmt->bind_param($typeStr, $params); to the $valArr loop results in a php warning: Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of elements in type definition string doesn't match number of bind variables in... and a mysqli error: No data supplied for parameters in prepared statement

Im still using the eval function to complete the binding. Unless, is there another way?

Comment: I just gave your code a quick test run and what I see is an error in the eval; You need to quote the right hand side.  `$Date = now();` is being evaled and `now()` is not a valid PHP function, the right hand side should be quoted.  You aren't getting this same error?

Comment: My apologies, Im actually quoting the now() function in the array to make it a string. so its $valArr = array( array(1, '\'NOW()\''), array(2, '\'NOW()\'') );. I wrote it incorrectly in my example above. I havent got far enough to confirm that would work as expected, but one step at a time.

Comment: Just tried replacing the NOW() function with PHP's date('Y-m-d') function in case that was the actual problem.. no dice

Comment: The date() call isn't going to work either, if it's not quoted.  The code the eval is producing would just be something like `$Date = 2012-8-1;` which at best is going to `eval()` to the arithmetic value 2012 minus 8 minus 1.  edit: maybe my hands overran my brain here, date() may be ok..

Comment: Tried with and without quotes.. same results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of continuing to try to get the existing code working, I'm going to suggest a KISS starting point, without the `prepare()`, the `eval()`, or the `bind_param()`.

```
  $cols = ['ID', 'Date'];
  $vals = [
    [1, '\'now()\''],
    [2, '\'now()\''],
  ];

  foreach ($vals as $val)
  {
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO table (' . implode($cols, ', ') . ') VALUES (' . implode($val, ', ') . ')';
    // exec here
  }
```

To make this a bit safer, you'll probably want to escape all the values before the implode, or before/as they are put into the array you're working with.  The existing code is, IMHO, trying to be too "clever" to do something so simple.

Alternately, you may want to consider switching to using the PDO library instead of mysqli.  PDO supports binding of named parameters on a per-parameter basis, which could be done in a loop without the eval().

Someone else may get the provided "clever" solution working instead of course.

Comment: I too was thinking that the simpler option might be the way to go. My only concern was with processing very large amounts of data. Really appreciate the help!

Comment: I don't think you have to worry about the data size here.  Prepared statements really help more on SELECT's when you're changing conditions like values in a WHERE clause.  With simple INSERTs like these, into a table with a small # of columns, there's not really an advantage.